# Symfony asset url when running from console

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to add a asset (image) full url (with domain and base) in a twig template when running from a command line (Console Command). It's meant to be sent to email.

The problem is, using absolute_url(asset()) doesn't include the host and base path when running on console.

Also, as specificed in http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/request_context.html, it just works for urls, not for assets.

I've also tried to set the router context when running from console:

```
$context = $this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext();
$context->setHost($defaultDomain);
$context->setScheme($scheme);
```

With no success. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To configure the Request Context - which is used by the URL Generator - you can redefine the parameters it uses as default values to change the default host (localhost) and scheme (http)

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
   router.request_context.host: example.org
   router.request_context.scheme: https
   router.request_context.base_url: my/path
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/request_context.html

```
#command
/** @var \Twig_Environment $twig */
$twig = $this->getContainer()->get('twig');
die($twig->render('view.html.twig'));

#view.html.twig
{{ absolute_url(asset('images/logo.png')) }}

#output
https://example.org/images/logo.png
```

Answer (score 0):

In my application, special for this situation with emails, i added global variable into Twig configuration:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        site_addr: "%site_addr%"
```

And setting this variable in parameters.yml

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
site_addr: https://some.site
```

And at last, in each email template i used this:

```
# AppBundle/Resources/views/Emails/layout.html.twig
<img src="{{ site_addr ~ asset('SomeAssetName') }}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `base_urls` parameter.

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_urls: ['http://localhost:8000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution which doesn't require adding any variable or parameter on config and is the same function that is used by Twig for `{{ absolute_url() }}`

```
public function yourAction(AssetsHelper $assetsHelper, HttpFoundationExtension $httpExtension)
{
    $assetsPath = $assetsHelper->getUrl('/img/test.jpg');
    $assetFullUrl = $httpExtension->generateAbsoluteUrl($assetPath);
}
```

The complete url of your asset will be on `$assetFullUrl`